# Find Value in Nested Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter, find

I'm trying to find a matching value within an array of objects.

I'm using `find` for the job, and that seems to work fine. But what if I need to assign more than one value to one of those keys?

Here's the current code:

```
const snack = "strawberry";

const fruits = [
    { label: "yellowFruit", value: "banana" },
    { label: "purpleFruit", value: "grape" },
    { label: "redFruit", value: "apple" },
    { label: "greenFruit", value: "waltermelon" },
];
```

And here's how I'm finding my value:

```
fruits.find(fruit => fruit.value === snack) || fruits[0]
```

I would actually need to associate two values to the label `redFruit` without duplicating that label, as shown below, but then `find` cannot do the job anymore.

Something like this:

```
const snack = "strawberry";

const fruits = [
    { label: "yellowFruit", value: "banana" },
    { label: "purpleFruit", value: "grape" },
    {
        label: "redFruit",
        value: [
            { val: "apple" },
            { val: "strawberry" }
        ]
    },
    { label: "greenFruit", value: "waltermelon" },
];
```

But finding `strawberry` with the below code doesn't match:

```
fruits.find(fruit => fruit.value === snacks) || fruits[0]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `snacks` is an object. how do you get the value from it?

Comment: Hi @NinaScholz, I've simplified the code to focus on my problem. Let's say that I want whatever I find in `fruits` to match the value of `snack`. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a different method based on the `value` property type, if the value is an array then use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to achieve the result.

```
let res = fruits.find(({ value }) => Array.isArray(value) ? value.some(({ val }) => val === snacks) : value === snacks) || fruits[0]
```

```js
const snacks = "strawberry";

const fruits = [{
    label: "yellowFruit",
    value: "banana"
  },
  {
    label: "purpleFruit",
    value: "grape"
  },
  {
    label: "redFruit",
    value: [{
        val: "apple"
      },
      {
        val: "strawberry"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "greenFruit",
    value: "waltermelon"
  },
];

let res = fruits.find(({ value }) => Array.isArray(value) ? value.some(({ val }) => val === snacks) : value === snacks) || fruits[0]

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep data simple:

```
const snack = "strawberry";

const fruits = [
    { label: "yellowFruit", value: "banana" },
    { label: "purpleFruit", value: "grape" },
    { label: "redFruit", value: "apple" },
    { label: "redFruit", value: "strawberry" },
    { label: "greenFruit", value: "waltermelon" },
];
```

... and your code will be simple too:

```
const result = fruits.find(({ value }) => value === snack)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so:

```js
const snack = "strawberry";

const fruits = [{
    label: "yellowFruit",
    value: "banana"
  },
  {
    label: "purpleFruit",
    value: "grape"
  },
  {
    label: "redFruit",
    value: [{
        val: "apple"
      },
      {
        val: "strawberry"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: "greenFruit",
    value: "waltermelon"
  },
];

let itemExists = fruits.some(item =>
  Array.isArray(item.value) ?
  item.value.some(subItem => subItem.val === snack) :
  item.value === snack);
  
console.log(itemExists);
```

By doing it this way you will receive
 a boolean whether or not the item exists.
Hope that helps,